# can a AWS S3 bucket have more than one policy attached to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket with policy1 attached to it and i attached another policy2 to same S3 bucket via cloudformation but its not showing up in S3 bucket properties => permissions => edit bucket policy.

can a AWS S3 bucket have more than one policy attached to it?

Comment: Remember that bucket policy configuration changes may not be instantaneously visible.  It is possible that you actually overwrote your policy but just didn't see it when you looked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, a `AWS::S3::BucketPolicy` can only have one `PolicyDocument`. However, a `PolicyDocument` can have multiple `Statement`s.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-policy.html#cfn-s3-bucketpolicy-policydocument